# How to add a trailing zero to a price?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I have a script which returns a price for a product. However, the price may or may not include trailing zeros, so sometimes I might have `258.22` and other times I might have `258.2`. In the latter case, I need to add the trailing zero. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can use javascript's `toFixed` method ([source](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-fixed-digits-after-decimal-places/)), you don't need jQuery.  Example:

```
var number = 258.2;    
var rounded = number.toFixed(2); // rounded = 258.20
```

Edit: Electric Toolbox link has succumbed to linkrot and blocks the Wayback Machine so there is no working URL for the source.

Comment: it is not working for integers. Think that number is '258' How can we do "258.00" ?

Comment: @CihanKüsmez, 258 should work. Are you trying with '258' (a string)?

Comment: but how can we converts into number because its giving string . 
@T.J.Crowder

Comment: @Mahi: Trailing zeros make no sense for a number, just a string (the *representation* of anumber).

Answer (score 14):

Javascript has a function - [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/ToFixed) - that should do what you want ... no JQuery needed.

```
var n = 258.2;
n.toFixed (2);  // returns 258.20
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think jQuery itself has any string padding functions (which is what you're looking for). It's trivial to do, though:

```
function pad(value, width, padchar) {

    while (value.length < width) {
        value += padchar;
    }
    return value;
}
```

**Edit** The above is great for strings, but for your specific numeric situation, [rosscj2533's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433122/how-to-add-a-trailing-zero-to-a-price-with-jquery/2433183#2433183) is the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the Internationalization API (Intl.NumberFormat function) with a configuration object.
Let's take an example

```
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { 
    minimumFractionDigits: 5
})

formatter.format(258.2) // output: 258.20000
formatter.format(258.22) // output: 258.22000
```