# Display trailing zero for price in jquery

Tags: jquery, decimal, zero, trailing

Hopefully someone can help with this.  I am simply looking to add the final zero to the decimal part of a price in a price calculator I am written.

The calculator starts with a user selecting a standard "Sign Up" fee of €25.50 and then selecting other packages to increase the price.

At the moment, the standard price displays as €25.5.

```
costs = jQuery('.cost-container').text();
total = Number(costs) + (25.50).toFixed(2);
```

I got this code by looking at the following similar query: [How to add a trailing zero to a price with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433122/how-to-add-a-trailing-zero-to-a-price-with-jquery)

Currently, if I enter 25.511 as my value, the result displays as 25.51, which shows that the code is sort of working, my issue is just when the second decimal place is 0 that it does not display.

Can anybody spot what is wrong?

Cheers

Damien

Comment: Did you try a `.append(0)` to the final price?

Comment: Add this line: `total = total.toFixed(2);` http://jsfiddle.net/DG69v/

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers.  @RobinvdA, whilst that seemed to work when I viewed it in the Console, the actual result still displayed as 25.5.  I had a look further down at some more of the code for the rest of the calculation and tried `costs = costs.toFixed(2)` and that solved my problem!  All working now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
costs = jQuery('.cost-container').text();
total = ( Number(costs) + 25.50 ).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Be careful with the use of "toFixed" cause it returns a string, use .toFixed(2)/1 to get a number

Comment: @frikinside After looking at the console, I did notice that the number was appearing as a string like you suggested, however adding a variation of `total = total.toFixed(2);` from @RobinvdA fixed the issue