# Adding ".00" When Returning Dollar Value Totals Via Math.js

Tags: javascript, math.js

In my MongoDB/Node backend I am doing some totaling of dollar amounts and returning that data to the front end. Note this is for displaying totals only, we're not altering the values themselves. Because we want two decimal places for the totaled dollar values, I am doing this:

```
let roundedTotalOpenBalance = math.round(totalOpenBalance, 2);
```

That will give me something like -- `322.45` -- which is what I want.

However, if the value total is `322`, I'd like to also pass that to the front end as `322.00`. How can I do this with math js? Or do I need to handle the transformation myself?

Comment: why not just add it in during the front end if youre going to display it there. Once the value becomes a string it's trivial to concatenate ".00" if it's an integer

Comment: Because we've decided we want to hand it to the front-end with this already done. Team decision.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2433188/2055998

Comment: @Muirik `toFixed` -> `returns a string representing the given number using fixed-point notation`

Comment: And if wrap that in parseFloat() I'm back where I started. Is there no simple way to handle this WITHOUT converting to a string?

Comment: You don't need to use math.js. Javascript handles this fine without any external libraries. The answer you accepted is basically the same as the accepted answer on the other question. I would expect this question to get closed eventually anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discard `Math.round()` and Try with [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```js
let num1 = 322.45;
let roundedTotalOpenBalance1 = num1.toFixed(2);
console.log(roundedTotalOpenBalance1);

let num2 = 322;
let roundedTotalOpenBalance2 = num2.toFixed(2);
console.log(roundedTotalOpenBalance2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a solution, ideally, that doesn't convert the value to a string the way toFixed() does.

Answer (score 1):

`roundedTotalOpenBalance.toFixed(2)` should do the trick :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed