# Zero removed after decimal point while Observable emitted the next value Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe, rxjs-observables

Here, In this example An observable is emitting values. But in console output, zeros after decimals are removed automatically.

I want to keep these zeros as it as after decimal. Is there a way to keep this zeros?

```
const numbers$ = of(1.440000, 2.40000, 3.0000);

numbers$.subscribe(
     value => console.log('Observable emitted the next value- ' + value)
);
```

Output:

```
Observable emitted the next value- 1.44   // need output as 1.440000
Observable emitted the next value- 2.4   // need output as 2.40000
Observable emitted the next value- 3    // need output as 3.0000
```

Comment: `1.440000` is just `1.44`. The only way would be to turn `of(1.440000, 2.40000, 3.0000)` into `of("1.440000", "2.40000", "3.0000")`

Comment: yes, i think you are right. No other solution than this. Thanks @Vivick

Answer (score 2):

This is not a rxjs issue, this is js behaviour.

```js
let numbers = [1.44000,1.20000,1.34234234];

numbers.forEach(x => console.log(x));

let precission = 4;

numbers.forEach(x => console.log(Number(x).toFixed(precission
)));
```

To receive the desired outcome you can use `toFixed` as seen here [How to add a trailing zero to a price?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433122/how-to-add-a-trailing-zero-to-a-price).
Keep in mind that this will cast the number to a string, so I would advise to add the "padding" zeroes as a last step, or even better by using the [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#decimalpipe) in the templates, where you want to show the values.

Comment: But I don't want to define let precission = 4 hard coded. Just want to display whatever number of zeros are coming after decimal, display amount as it is without any modification. like 1.20000 , 1.22200000

Comment: Then you should pass them as strings in your producer e.g. 
`
const numbers$ = of("1.440000", "2.40000", "3.0000");

numbers$.subscribe(
     value => console.log('Observable emitted the next value- ' + value)
);
`

Comment: Correct, only string format can help me here. Thanks for this.

Comment: Please add such informations to your question.