Trailing zero issue in angular
I have a method which returning a number
In that method I have a string,='1.10' and converting to number using Number method
Getting output as 1.1,but actually i need 1.10
Tried Number, parseFloat ,+ all methods not able to achieve this in angular

This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78182239/zero-removed-after-decimal-point-while-observable-emitted-the-next-value-angular/78182350#78182350

a number doesn't have trailing zeros. If you need that for display purposes only, use Number.toFixed() to create a string in the format you desire ...

Numbers do not have trailing zeros on either size.
1.1 -> valid
1.10 -> invalid number
01.1 -> invalid number
If you have a requirement to show the output with trailing zeros, use angular DecimalPipe
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div>string: {{str}}</div>
    <div>number: {{num}}</div>
    <div>number fomatted with decimal pipe: {{num | number: '0.2-2'}}</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  str: string = '1.10';
  num: number = parseFloat(this.str);
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

My case I am taking hour and minus adding into string example 1.12 mins or 1.10 mins.But return type is number and the method is reused everywhere i can't make that a string .So I want 1.10 as a number.So i can proper use that number in other methods

@Varun007 Javascript does not allow that, 1.10 is an impossible number, you need to do the calculations without using trailing zeros, so 1.1 instead of 1.10, this value can only exist in javascript as a string!

You could create custom pipe for that:
ng g p trailing-zero

then modify it to:
@Pipe({ name: 'trailingZero', standalone: true })
export class TrailingZeroPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number | string, fractionDigits: number = 1): string {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
      value = Number(value);
    }
    return value.toFixed(fractionDigits);
  }
}

If you are using NgModule import it otherwise if your app is based on standalone just import where you want to use it.
Here is working demo of stackblitz
